# PHP: how to create an regexp to preg_match() for PT Mobile phones?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, mobile-phones

i'm newer related to Regexp on **PHP**...

I need to create an **Regexp** to filter Portuguese Mobile Phones, can anybody help me and explain how i do it? (To i understand it)

**Rules:**

```
The integer/string must have 9chars;
The first char must be a '9';
The second one can be '1,2,3,6' (Chars are separeted by commas);
The other chars must be in range of '0-9';
```

Comment: I'd add some examples of strings that do and don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#9[1236][0-9]{7}#
```

That should do it ;)

Explanation:

```
# <-- delimiter
    9 <-- 9
    [1236] <-- either of the chars in the brackets
    [0-9]{7} <-- 0-9  7 times
# <-- delimiter
```

Use: If you want to check whether something is a valid phone number, use:

```
$isValid = preg_match('#^9[1236][0-9]{7}$#', $phoneNumber);
```

Notice the `^` and `$`. These ensure there is only the phone number and nothing more.

Comment: thank you for the explaination, i was trying with / and not #, what's the diference?

Comment: It would have worked with `/`, too. I simply mostly use `#` or `~` as delimiters, because they occure less often within the regular expression itself and therefore you need to do less escaping.