# Regular Expression extracting all existent Portugal Mobile number

Tags: php, regex, mobile

I need a way to extract mobile numbers from post messages.

Portugal mobile starts with 91 or 92 or 93 or 96. Right now I have `preg_match(#^9[1236][0-9]{7})`.

The problem is sometimes on the message they post something like this way:

> (2 numbers together, or some of numbers have space between them)
>
> Example1: text text 919 919 919 text
>
> Example2: text text 919919919 text
>
> Example3: 919919919 929929929 text
>
> Example4: text text text text 919 919 919 929999999
>
> Example5: text 3832 text 1 text 919 999 999 929 999 999 text
>
> Example6: text 3832
>
> Example7: text 123 text 007 text 91 9919919
>
> text 1 text 919999999 929999999 text
>
> Regex to match those examples, please watch example 5 and 6, which makes this more complicated
>
> Portugal Mobile Numbers starts with 91/92/93/96

I need extract all match numbers and `array_push()` all the matches into an array, then `array_unique` them, making sure there is no repeated numbers.

Could someone show me an example of regex for this and example PHP code please?

Comment: do you need the `text -text` or spaces? If not, just do a `preg_replace('/\D/', '', $number)` first to remove any formatting. Then you can match it with your expression.

Comment: i was using filter_var FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT function to remove all non int stuff, so i may have cases which can be "text 999 text 919999999 text 929999999 919 999 999" which filters to "999919999999929999999919999999", those phone numbers are mixed with text, sometimes phonenumbers comes with space for 3 phone digits, case1: text+number+number filter out both number and array_push both matches, case2: text number(with 3spaces) text, i wanna extract all those strings with 9 digits (by regex, with and with no space between every 3 digits)

Comment: i will edit the Question to look better

Comment: What is that pound sign and why do you need it? This is too somple. Can you post your regex alone, and what is passing and what is failing?

Comment: What about something like http://regex101.com/r/gB8xQ7 ?

Comment: which & do you mean #? i took example from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259334/php-how-to-create-an-regexp-to-preg-match-for-pt-mobile-phones

Comment: Thanks for updating your original post with examples, @BingLin. It helps to know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be fairly certain that the numbers posted to that board are in groups of 3 (### ### ###) or a long run of 9 (#########) or even 3+6 (### #######), and you are guaranteed that the numbers start with 9[1236], I'd suggest this:

```
(9[1236]\d) ?(\d{3}) ?(\d{3})
```

or slightly more verbose:

```
(9[1236][0-9]) ?([0-9]{3}) ?([0-9]{3})
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/fP8tK3

It looks for a 9[1236], another number, and optionally a space, then any 3 digits, another optional space, and 3 more digits.

Answer (score 0):

A modification to the suggestion by Jonathan Kuhn.

Say the value of your $number variable is "aaaaaa 92 999 9999 aaaaaa"

Fist your pattern would need to match all the non-digit characters before the numbers and strip them.

```
$pattern = '/\D+/';
```

This matches any non-digit character (\D), and the + implies to match one or more of these characters.

using preg_replace you can then do:

```
preg_replace ($pattern,'',$number);
```

This should remove all characters up to the first digit.
To remove the non-digit characters to the right, you would have to modify the pattern slightly to:

```
$pattern = '/\D+$/';
```

We added the dollar sign here to match from the end of the string. running preg_replace again would strip non-digit characters to the right of the phone number.

Edited:
Now to match example 5 and 6, we would need a regular expression like so:

```
/(\d{3}[ //-]*){3}/g
```

to find numbers like 999999999, 999 999 999, 999-999-999, 999/999/999.

You can now use the preg_match function to retrieve your results.

Comment: What happens with two numbers in a row?  `919999999 929999999` The \D would strip the space from between them and give `919999999929999999` wouldn't it?

Comment: Yep it definitely would, but I figured its one number per string; would have to make mods otherwise.

Comment: @OnlineCop, I just added the pattern for the last issue you raised, I believe it should cover all OPs points now.

Comment: OnlineCop (9[1236][0-9]) ?([0-9]{3}) ?([0-9]{3}) seens working fine with all another cases, but ## ####### seens failing, but its not a huge issue on example7, ty very everyone!

Comment: i made small edit (9[1236] ?[0-9]) ?([0-9]{3}) ?([0-9]{3}), this seens matching all all 7 examples now, added space+? on 1st subpattern, by logic, looks like space+? means space can be optionally be here to match :)

Comment: Very nice, and short.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is what I did for to only accept the number binging with 91/92/93/96 by the way this will only accept numbers, so if they try entering a key this will not accept.

```
/^([9][1236])[0-9]*$/
```

The Regex Bellow is to allow white spaces (Edited based on edited answer)

```
/^([9][1236\s])[0-9\s]*$/
```

Comment: How does this work with numbers that contain spaces, like `919 999 999`?

Comment: @OnlineCop looks like he changed the question, when I read it, there wasn't anything about spaces

Comment: this may not work, some people like to use one space between/for each 3 digits, so numbers 919 919 919 or 919919919 are variants